# Compare 2 pivot tables side by side

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a pivot table gathering data from a sheet, using slicers i'm able to filter data.

What i wanted to do is get data from 2 slicers, like one slicer with March and another with June and show it side by side within the same pivot table or different, So I can compare data.

I'm using Excel, any ideas?

Let me know if there is anything else u might need to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before creating any slicers, copy your pivot table and place beside the original table. Then create your Slicer on Pivot 1, and repeat for Pivot 2. These will be exclusive slicers as long as you do it in this order.

[image]